# Terminology for a logical pairing of 2 binary bits

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, nomenclature

Four bits is a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and eight bits is a [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). Is there any formal or established nomenclature for a logical pairing of **two bits**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not any *formal* or *established* nomenclature for two-bit entities. But a variety of terms do exist, some of which are listed in the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nybble.html), which says:

> ...there have been quite a few analogical attempts to construct unambiguous terms for bit blocks of other sizes. **All of these are strictly jargon, not techspeak**, and **not very common** jargon at that.

<sub><sup>Emphasis mine.</sup></sub>

For a two-bit quantity, ibid. says:

> 2 bits:   crumb, quad, quarter, tayste, tydbit, morsel

Comment: Do you start by saying "No" because you feel the 'Jargon File' you pointed out is in some way frivolous? Why do you seem to consider your answer not-definitive?